# C++/WinRT call function from another class

Tags: c++

I've checked a few questions but they don't seem to work. I'm trying to make a Settings Page where you press the back button, the frame containing the settings page collapses.

### SettingsPage.xaml.cpp:

```
void SettingsPage::BackButton_Click(Platform::Object ^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs ^ e)
{
    MainPage mainPage;
    mainPage.SettingsBackButtonClick();
}
```

### MainPage.xaml.cpp:

```
void MainPage::SettingsBackButtonClick()
{
    SettingsHolder->Visibility = ::Visibility::Collapsed;
}
```

the code in SettingsPage.xaml.cpp does not seem to call the code in MainPage.xaml.cpp.

Comment: Your `BackButton_Click` method creates a local instance of `MainPage` and changes the visibility of some XAML element that is part of it. This is a MainPage that is unrelated to the MainPage in your XAML tree. So you changed the visibility of something that isn't visible anyway. You need to get to the MainPage instance that is in your XAML tree. There are any number of ways of doing this. (Pass it as a navigation parameter, keep it in a global variable, walk the XAML tree looking for it...) (Also, you say C++/WinRT, but the code looks like a mix of C++/WinRT and C++/CX.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm sorry, could you clarify your response?